# HQL variables Filter cases

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hql

how to update my code to accept the filter 
HQL 4 variables Filter cases 
let x , y , z ;

```
{

select data from my table  
where   x = :x And y = :y And z =:z
}
if send x , y , z is NULL > 
{
select data from my table


}
```

how to edited this

or send x , y NULL

```
{
select data from my table  
where   x = :x And y = :y  
}
```

summary : how to do Dynamic select stamen.
use :
1.spring boot
2.JPA
3.hibernate
3.HQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a trick you can use :

```
SELECT data
FROM my_table
WHERE (:x IS NULL OR x = :x)
  AND (:y IS NULL OR y = :y)
  AND (:z IS NULL OR z = :z)
```

---

**Note the check :** `:x IS NULL` it will check the passed parameter value is null or not.

For example if you have this case :

```
X       Y          Z
null    not null   not null
```

Your query is equivalent to :

```
SELECT data FROM my_table WHERE AND y = :y AND z = :z
```

---

The check of X is ignored.

Comment: is null, what's do??

Comment: if x = null :
SELECT data
FROM my_table
WHERE  (:y IS NULL OR y = :y)
  AND (:z IS NULL OR z = :z)

do this ???

Comment: @hOS then x will be ignored, for example is x is null and y and z not, then your query is equivalent to `SELECT data
FROM my_table WHERE   AND y = :y  AND z = :z`